# Translate Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, localisation

In my customer/login.php 's template I've this:

```
<?php echo $this->__("If you are an " .$name . "'s dealer and still do not have a password to access the reserved area, request in"); ?>
```

Then in app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/it_IT
i've

```
If you are an %s's dealer and still do not have a password to access the reserved area, request in %s,Se sei un concessionario %s e ancora non hai la password di accesso all'Area Riservata, richiedila a %s
```

But this translation doesn't work. Why? Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

you need to add this to your template:

```
<?php echo $this->__("If you are an %s's dealer and still do not have a password to access the reserved area, request in", $name); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

try with quotes:

```
"If you are an %s's dealer and still do not have a password to access the reserved area, request in %s","Se sei un concessionario %s e ancora non hai la password di accesso all'Area Riservata, richiedila a %s"
```

also this line needs variable I think

```
<?php echo $this->__("If you are an " .$name . "'s dealer and still do not have a password to access the reserved area, request in ".$name); ?>
```

Comment: why downvote???

Comment: What's the point of using %s if you're not using sprintf, or the optional arguments of __()?